# Software to convert .m2ts to .mts (HD video files)

Tags: video, conversion, mts, m2ts

I am looking to convert some of .m2ts video files (about 80GB worth) to .mts format which the my current camera is produces natively.  Is there any free software that anyone has used that can do this?

I know the .m2ts is the container so I am not sure just doing a rename of the extension to .mts is valid.  It works but I am not sure it is actually producing an mts stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from some web readings, when you are talking about AVCHD, there is no difference between the .mts and .m2ts files. The following sources may be helpful for you:

- [AV Science Forum](http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=1097703) (Difference
  between *.mts and *.m2ts files)
- [Creative COW](http://forums.creativecow.net/readpost/24/906989) (MTS vs M2TS)
- [Vimeo Help Center](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:10916) (MTS files vs
  M2TS files)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a backup of all your m2ts files in case of file damaged, and try to rename m2ts to mts, mts is also a container format, in general it is ok to do so.